# What graphic languages are simpler than SVG for database diagrams?

Tags: 2d, vector-graphics, diagram

This is PNG was exported from Inkscape.  I created it manually and used the
connector tool to link tables.

I find the plain SVG for this diagram more complicated than I was expecting so would like to know if there are simpler graphic languages or specifications for this task?

I would like to write something using Python.

Here's the pastebin: [SVG for database diagram](http://pastebin.com/PDEupPFr)

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for here? This looks like Dot-graph territory, not API territory. Obviously, since Dot is just a text file, you can write it with any programming language. Are you looking for a program to create such things or a programmatic way to generate such an image?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about computer graphics. I'm am not sure what would be a good place on SE to ask it though. Also, as Nicol points out, it need to be better formulated.

Answer (score 1):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a popular tool for making network diagrams. It takes a text format ("DOT language") describing the nodes and edges as input, and can render the resulting diagram to SVG or other image formats.

Comment: yEd is also nice. altough in this case creating a dot file is the way to go.